# Why sometimes table scan is faster then index scan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I created a table to test the amount of logical blocks that are being read and the execution plan chosen by the query optimizer, comparing the queries when this table has index and when it hasn't.

the test table is

```
 create table scan
 ( 
      id int identity(1, 1), 
      a varchar(10), 
      b varchar(10),
      c varchar(10), 
      d varchar(10), 
      e varchar(10), 
      f varchar(10) 
)
```

When I run of of these queries:

```
select * from scan
select id from scan
```

I got 88 and 58 logical reads, and a table scan algorithm

Then I alter the table putting the pk constraint and his clustered id

```
alter table scan
add constraint fk_id primary key (id)
```

then a run the same queries:

```
select * from scan
select id from scan
```

and I got 90 and 60 scan reads and the index scan algorithm

The question is: if the query optimizer choose the best way to run the query, why it is choosing the index scan if the table scan can read less block?

Comment: You're just reading all the rows -- the index isn't doing anything.  Add a WHERE clause and see what happens.

Comment: The query optimizer *predicts* the best way to run the query.  It is not generally possible for it to *know* the best way without examining the data, which would defeat the purpose.  As a result, it will not always choose the absolute best strategy, but it should be pretty reliable about choosing a very good one.  Your data do not suggest otherwise.

Comment: Are your numbers the *actual* reads or the *estimated* reads?  On such a small table, an index is not likely to be particularly useful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, those numbers I got using SET STATISTICS IO ON. Check my comment in the answer above. That is my doubt about these numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created the primary key constraint, it was made clustered by default. This means that the heap you had previously has been ordered by this key (`id`, in your case).

Data in tables can be stored in either one of two ways: either heaps or clustered indices. When the latter is created, the former is gone. So it is impossible for SQL Server to perform table scan on index - it can only be an index scan (clustered index scan, btw - this is important).

I know it may sound confusing, but try to read some basics on clustered indices - it might help.

Comment: But I still don't know why it is reading more block with index than it reads with table scan. Without index I have 7 columns, imagine that each one has 1kb and the block is 14kb, so it reads 2 rows per block. With index we have 2 columns, one for the index and another for the pointer to row adress. If thy have also 1kb each, the block know will have 7 lines. So I am reading more information with less blocks. I think that it should read either less blocks than table scan or much more block than table scan in case of SELECT *, because it will read the "index table" and the real table.

Comment: @Mucida, heap is physically implemented as a double linked list, where every table page has 2 pointers - on the previous and on the next pages in the heap. Clustered index is implemented as a B-tree, so it consumes slightly more space for root and intermediate level pages (about 1% of table size, on average). Depending on whether your table is a heap or not, either table scan (that is, a heap scan) or a clustered index scan will be used. And you can't have both structures on disk for the same table at the same time - it's only one table, after all.

Comment: thanks, I got the idea about the space. But why if I execute this query "SELECT id, a FROM Scan WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 9999" it is still using table scan? Why it is not going to the table with id sorted and the row address, looking just the block with the corresponding search and then going to the addresses to look for the "a" values? The index at id is useless in this case. If I create an index with "id" AND "a" then it works faster doing index seek.

Comment: by the way, I just checked that if the id is non-clustered, it does the table scan on that query, but if it is clsutered it does a index seek. Now I am really confused lol

Comment: I got it. With a table that has 30k rows, it used table scan. Using a table with 200K rows it used index seek, RID lookup and nested loops

Comment: Yes, query optimiser uses a set of somewhat arcane algorithms to determine how big part of a table your query will end up retrieving. As the `selected pages/total pages` ratio goes down (either by increasing the table size or by narrowing search criteria), at some point it begins to favour seek over scan.

Comment: I read that RID is a pointer to the rows and it is smaller than indexes id's. They are used at heap tables, that is why smaller tables use RID even if the table has a non-clustered index. So why it is using RID lookup algorithm and the index seek together?

Comment: @Mucida, because at some point it decides that it would be cheaper to quickly locate rows using non-clustered index and then perform some RID lookups (which are quite expensive) than scanning the entire heap table. It's all about costs.

Comment: I am selecting a column w that has non clustered id and another one that has no index. I think that for small amount of rows they use index seek to get the row id(index) and RID to get the row "a" and a loop to combine de results... if we have several rows as result, it prefer table scan than the cost o use RID to get the "a" column

Comment: @Mucida, yes, it works like that. There are several other criteria in this equation, too, but generally it's all about IO. Btw, you can always try to force some particular strategy using hints and compare the resulting execution plans and their effectiveness. Unless statistics are outdated or indices fragmented horribly, it's quite rare for query optimizer to miss the point.